# Unable to set the receive response in the queue specified in the URI

Tags: rabbitmq, rpc, wso2-esb

We are am using WSO2 ESB 6.5.0 and RabbitMQ as a message broker. We set the rabbitmq.replyto.name parameter as follows :

`<address uri="rabbitmq:/DPH_CalRed?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=guest&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=guest&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=queue1&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=exchange1&amp;rabbitmq.replyto.name=queue2"/>`

But it seems that the sender ignores the customized queue and uses a temporary exclusive queue named "amqp.gen...."

We also tried by setting Transport Headers property REPLY_TO and using the Default Endpoint, but we get the same result.

Is there any solution to force the sender to use the customized durable queue as a reply to queue?

Comment: This is a known issue (https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/4309) and has been fixed in the latest version of EI (EI 7). This fix will be available in the upcoming EI 6.x releases as well.